# chmod command to set a file as permission denied

Tags: chmod

I want my file not to be deleted by any user. Can I know the chmod mode command for the same?

I need to get this kind of msg (rm ctl_model_fact.csv: Permission denied)

Answer (score 3):

`root` can always delete a file (at least on the `chmod` level; you need file system attributes or a Linux Security Module (SELinux, AppArmor) to prevent that).

For ordinary users you have to remove the write permission of the parent directory for all users.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're not trying to keep root from deleting the file, you actually need to modify the permissions on the directory in which `ctl_model_fact.csv` resides. `chmod go-w [your directory]` will do it, but it will affect all files in your directory, not just `ctl_model_fact.csv`. If you also want to make sure other users are unable to *change* the file, use `chmod go-w ctl_model_fact.csv`.

Answer (score 2):

Deletion is a write operation so you need to remove write access from the directory that contains the file (using the file `~/foo/bar.txt` as an example):

```
chmod a-w ~/foo/
```

or

```
chmod 666 ~/foo/
```

This, however still allows root to delete the file. If don't even want to allow that, things get more complex. [As far as I know](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73768/22222), the best way (and this is easily circumvented by reversing the command) is to set it to "immutable":

```
sudo chattr +i ~/foo/bar.txt
```

That will stop root from deleting the file but they can always just run `chattr -i ~/foo/bar.txt` again to undo it so it's more like a obstacle than a full block. It does, however, stop non-root users from deleting it and they won't have the right to run `chattr -i` on it so this is the easiest way since it does not affect all files in the directory.